# Tf.einsum vs matmul for computing density matrix from a set of Cholesky decomposed matrices

Tags: density-matrix, programming

I am trying to construct a density matrix of shape `256x256` from a set of T matrices. These T matrices are all Cholesky-decomposed matrices. But I am not sure if the code is right or my approach is right; one of the reasons is that when I change from `tf.einsum` to `tf.matmul` some error is raised. I am not very well used to use einsum, that is the main reason I am trying to change the following code:

```
def density_matrix_from_T(tmatrix):
    """
    Gets density matrices from T matrices and normalizes them.

    Args:
        tmatrix (`tf.Tensor`): A tensor (N, hilbert_size, hilbert_size)
                               representing N valid T matrices.

    Returns:
        rho (`tf.Tensor`): A tensor of shape (N, hilbert_size, hilbert_size)
                           representing N density matrices.
    """
    T = tmatrix
    T_dagger = tf.transpose(T, perm=[0, 2, 1], conjugate=True)
    proper_dm = tf.matmul(T_dagger, T)
    all_traces = tf.linalg.trace(proper_dm)
    all_traces = tf.reshape(1 / all_traces, (-1, 1))
    rho = tf.einsum("bij,bk->bij", proper_dm, all_traces)

    return rho
```

where the T matrix came from:

```
def clean_cholesky(img):
    """
    Cleans an input matrix to make it the Cholesky decomposition matrix T

    Args:
        img (`tf.Tensor`): a tensor of shape (batch_size, hilbert_size,
                                                          hilbert_size, 2)
                           representing random outputs from a neural netowrk.
                           The last dimension is for separating the real and
                           imaginary part.

    Returns:
        T (`tf.Tensor`): a 3D tensor (N, hilbert_size, hilbert_size)
                           representing N matrices used for Cholesky decomp.
    """
    real = img[:, :, :, 0]
    imag = img[:, :, :, 1]

    diag_all = tf.linalg.diag_part(imag, k=0, padding_value=0)
    diags = tf.linalg.diag(diag_all)

    imag = imag - diags
    imag = tf.linalg.band_part(imag, -1, 0)
    real = tf.linalg.band_part(real, -1, 0)
    T = tf.complex(real, imag)
    
    return T
```

When I use it like this, it works fine but when I compute Fidelity to compare the reconstructed density matrix with a given original matrix, it gives a very poor result (something like 0.01 when a good result is close to 1). Anyway, I believe the problem is with `rho = tf.einsum("bij,bk->bij", proper_dm, all_traces)` and then I tried to change it to `rho = tf.matmul(proper_dm, all_traces)` but it raises an error on incompatibility:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'density_matrix_1' (type DensityMatrix).

{{function_node __wrapped__BatchMatMulV2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0
device:CPU:0}} Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,256,256], In[1]: [1,1]     [Op:BatchMatMulV2]

Call arguments received by layer 'density_matrix_1' (type DensityMatrix):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 256, 256, 2), dtype=float64)
  • training=True
```

The arguments `bij, bk -> bij` are independent of the input size? I mean, does it matter if the input is a matrix of shape 5x5 or 459x459? Or it is just dependent on the shape of the array in the sense that if it is a 2D or 3D array?

If I don't want (and I really don't want) to use `tf.einsum` how can I correctly change it to use matmul?